# Use limit in CQL with range

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

How to set limit on cassandra DB and set the range not just limit because I have to find 10 to 100 record from cassandra DB

I have one table user 
i want to search only 100 user then next 100 use means i want to paginate it so Please tell me How this can implement in our cassandra (CQL)

Answer (score 0):

You can use datastax java driver for the same, its very easy to use.
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientCreate_t.html

And please refer the following
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0

Comment: I didn't want to connect with cassandra just want to knw about if we have 1 table with 10000 record then select * from table_name limit 0,25   I just wanted to write this query in cql

Comment: you can do it by using some condition in where clause like, select * form table where token(idcolumn-name) > tokeb(idcolumn-value) limit 20. For next time provide the last row key vaule as idcolumn-value.

Comment: but you cannot do it with pagination if then tell me how you can paginate the data

Comment: Like first fetch some i.e. 20 row using limit and where clause on start key, and in next iteration use 20th rowkey as a start key and after that 40th rowkey and so on...